# How to style angular text blocks

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a status var in a scope of a controller.
Whenever my rest PUT succeeds I append a message to this js variable.
I show it in my template using `{{status}}`

How can I style this? I tried inserting `<br>` tags in this text but they just show up as regular text and dont insert a new line. How can I also bold certain tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for HTML to be rendered, use `ng-bind-html`

```
<div ng-bind-html="status"></div>
```

P.S. Don't forget to import `ngSanitize` module into your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

about ng-class directive

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a  tag or a  tag to wrap your {{status}}, and add to the tag an `id` or `classes` with styles?